# wordpress: detecting rewrite rules flush

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have my own plugin that, on activation, adds some rewrite rules which map url's to single page applications.

Now, I lose the rules once in a while, after some other plugin updates or maybe another process that triggers `flush_rewrite_rules` in Wordpress.

The problem is, I do not know when, how or why it happens. And by whom.

So I have searched globally in my WP files and come up with the following actions that trigger a refresh

`add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_saved',          array( $this, 'load' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_added',         array( $this, 'load' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_updated',       array( $this, 'load' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_deleted',       array( $this, 'load' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_install',                          array( $this, 'load' ) );
        add_action( 'after_db_upgrade',                    array( $this, 'load' ) );
        add_action( 'after_switch_theme',                    array( $this, 'load' ) );`

When one of those actions are triggered, I reload my rules.
That works, when one of those triggers.
So probably, once in a while another one triggers that I can't find.
Or maybe the flush happens after the action triggers, rendering my load useless.

So, is there a better way to hook into a flush so that I can add my own rules there automatically?
Now we figure it out a couple of days later when someone complains that the app is not working and I have to load the rules again.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of options; fixing the symptoms, or tracking down the cause.

**Fixing the symptoms**

At the end of the [`WP_Rewrite::rewrite_rules()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L1226) function is a filter `rewrite_rules_array`:

```
$this->rules = apply_filters( 'rewrite_rules_array', $this->rules );
```

You could hook into that and make your rules are there (adding them if they don't exist).  Hook it with a high number for the `$priority` argument, in case the rules are being removed using the same hook.

**Tracking down the cause**

Alternatively, you could change the [`flush_rewrite_rules`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L238) function itself (assuming that's the entry point for the rogue changes that are deleting your rules), and have it email you a stack trace whenever it's called.  It might help you track down the cause.  Something like (*completely* untested):

```
function flush_rewrite_rules( $hard = true ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $e = new Exception();
    wp_mail ( 'you@example.com', 'flush_rewrite_rules called', $e->getTraceAsString() );

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules( $hard );
}
```

Obviously that change is only temporary, until you have a lead on the problem - I'd never advocate changing core code permanently.

If that doesn't work, you may need to put it deeper into `$wp_rewrite`, like the [`generate_rewrite_rules`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L872) function.

Comment: I think I will combine both your answers: add my rules if they don't from my own plugin (so no core hacking). And write something in my debug.log when the flush happens. That way I can trace it down and hopefully nail it once and for all.